# Does IIS have a log?

Tags: iis, logging, windows-event-log

I have a secure web site but I did not configure permissions to let the IIS worker process access the respective machine certificate's private key. Naturally, navigation to the site does not work.

I want to know how can one troubleshoot this situation? I cannot find any relevant logs. I mean, I do have the logs in c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\, but I have yet to discover any meaningful information there...

I need it for IIS6 and IIS7.

Comment: I guess you can try to raise log level, but I'm not IIS-guy ...

Comment: It would really help to know what version of IIS you're running? Also, you checked the system and application event logs, correct?

Comment: IIS logs predominantly contain information about the requests themselves.  Look in the event logs for issues with the server config.

Comment: Guys, guys. Please, consider me an IIS ignoramus. I do not know how to raise the IIS log level, I do not know how to enable per issue log.

Comment: The event log is silent. How can I enable it for IIS?

Comment: Hopefully you have logs ! In some countries it could have legal issues if that wasn't the case (ex: in France, you HAVE TO store AT LEAST 1 year of (HTTP(S)) logs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this isn't over simplistic. There are website logs, which log HTTP and such request. If do this on a site level, you'll need to enable that, done very simply through IIS7 by going to site in features views, open logging, and click enable on the right.

For IIS6: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313437

[image]

There are also logs generated by IIS that are put into the Application Log of the server dealing w/ .Net and such, and some in the system log dealing with app pools, the actual .exes of the worker processes. If you have Server 2008, it's really easy to drill down to view those logs. Go into Server Manager, Roles, Web Server and box is a pre-filter log for your viewing pleasure.